# WPF: State of Minimized System.Windows.Window

Tags: wpf, windows, window-position

How do I know whether the System.Windows.Window was in WindowState.Normal or WindowState.Maximized before it was minimized?

Comment: Use 2 variables, say currentState and previousState.  Update them with the StateChanged event.

Comment: I really don't want to handle Window state changes in my code. Is there no way to access pre-minimized state through Windows object in a similar way to pre-minimized coordinates (Window.RestoreBounds)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't unless you keep track of the previous state yourself:

```
private WindowState _previousState = WindowState.Normal;
private void MainWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        if (_previousState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Window was in maximized state before being minimized");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Window was in normal state before being minimized");
        }
    }
    _previousState = WindowState;
}
```

I am afraid there is no "PreviousWindowState" property available.

Comment: That is so annoying! Thanks for the clarification though.